# Create grid using OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, grid, mesh

I want to create a grid of squares (similar to a circular mesh) for an Android application in order to do some image reconstruction for biomedical imaging, similar to what is shown in the picture below. [image]

I know that I can draw squares (by drawing 2 triangles) using the OpenGL library in Android. But is there a faster way to create that many small squares on the screen? And most importantly, I need to be able to colour these squares according to some data that I will receive via Bluetooth.

OpenGL seems to be very brutal to do this because colour and squares are set in a very user unfriendly way, if you want many.

Thank you for any insight you may have.

Comment: That is a lot of detail for a mobile screen. Also you don't mention if the user needs to zoom in/out, if each square is a touch target, or if redraw speed is really important. Note making a great user's experience doesn't mean that the developer's experience in producing it will be the same. You should at least explain if you tried Android's Canvas and what is lacking.

Comment: Also, as a general comment about solving problems where the provided API seems to be hostile to the result you're trying to achieve, it's time to build a ladder of abstractions! :) In this case, you probably want to be able to generate a display list of OpenGL commands, so you'll need something like the following:
- buildSquare(color)
- buildLine(yOffset, rowColors) -> uses buildSquare()
- buildMesh(radius, colorMap) -> uses buildLine()
-

Comment: @MorrisonChang No, I don't need any of those extras. I just need a simple grid like that, and I want to be able to colour in the squares of the grid off of some data that I get from Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to extract what the question is here. "Is there a faster way to create that many small squares on the screen?": Yes, if these are static then simply use an image for grid and display it. If it needs to be done programmatically you can draw it to texture once and then reuse it.

To fill specific fields with some color you will need to use the 2 triangles procedure. But again the question is if you need to do this only once or every time the view gets "dirty". If only once then you may again simply draw to texture and display that. You might actually be able to just draw to your main buffer and never clear it as well.

As for being "unfriendly" for drawing squares I completely disagree. Create a method `drawRect(MyRect rect)` in conjunction with orthographical matrix and you may have yourself very controlled environment. For instance you may have an NxN grid and can setup ortho matrix using `(0, N, 0, N*(screenHeight/screenWidth))` values and your result is that your coordinate system is normalized so each square is 1x1. That means indexed array in for loop with `i,j` would mean using something as easy as `drawRect(MyRect(j, i, 1, 1, colors[j][i]))`.

To be fair chances are limitless. It is really up to you on how you will make your data source and transform that to a drawing. It all really depends on what you want your end result to be like and what features you need. For instance if you want to have some "undo" functionality you will already need to redraw the whole thing and drawing to texture will have no use.

Comment: I can't use an image, because I want to fill in the square colours with data that I receive via Bluetooth. Essentially it's similar to a color plot.

Comment: I just want to generate this grid, and then continuously refresh its colours with new data. So are you saying that I should

Comment: @stellarhawk34 What you are saying looks perfect for using a texture... You can actually create a raw mutable NxN byte buffer on memory and then update its pixels when you retrieve new data. Then all you do is push this data to GPU as texture or use glTexSubImage2D which will update only a portion of the data (1 pixel for instance).

Comment: Thanks for your message. Because I'm fairly new to all this, are you suggesting that I use the TextureView class (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) If yes, do you maybe have any idea where I should start to generate this circular grid?

Comment: To further clarify by the way, I want the final image to look something like that coloured circular plot you see in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqgwBc7cGZ8 And I don't need 316 squares, as my picture shows. I can do with less than 50 squares.

Comment: @stellarhawk34 No, all you need is a normal view for open GL. A surface view if I remember correctly. Then you can generate image data kid of "int ***buffer[width][height][4]". Then fill these data with what you get from BT and then update the texture. So you need the code to draw a textured rectangle on screen (should be easy to find). Those pixels discarded by circle should only be transparent, nothing more.

Comment: Because I feel I have insufficient programming experience or knowledge of this OpenGL, would it be possible to make this grid I am talking about using a bitmap, and colouring in individual pixels? If I make a 256 by 256 bitmap, I would have a circular grid of approximately 51000 pixels. And then I can access and colour in each pixel, in a very easy way I believe. Can you confirm if this would be a way to go?

Comment: @stellarhawk34 I can confirm this is one of the ways. I am not sure it is relatively a good one but it should work.